# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong in the code?

I've tried to search for this particular case and could not find the answer.  I've also tried to use example from the [official docs on `sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), but couldn't get it to work.  Basically, I have a lot of data in `inc_data` that I need to insert into sqlite3.

```
import sqlite3

inc_data = [[u'Period Ending', u'Dec 31, 2012', u'Dec 31, 2011', u'Dec 31, 2010'],
            [u'Total Revenue\n', u'104,507,000\n', u'106,916,000\n', u'99,870,000\n'],
            ]


conn = sqlite3.connect("inc_data.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''DROP TABLE inc_table''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE inc_table
             (item text, value1 text, value2 text, value3 text)''')

c.execute('INSERT INTO inc_table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', inc_data)

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

The error msg:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO inc_table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', inc_data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: inc_table
```

many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the title.. I answered your *title* error instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed in *two* items; each a list of parameters.

Either use `c.executemany()` (which does expect a sequence of sequences), or loop over `inc_data` to give `c.execute()` *one* set of bind values:

```
# insert multiple rows; one for each entry in `inc_data`
c.executemany('INSERT INTO inc_table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', inc_data)

# or loop
for bind_values in inc_data:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO inc_table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', bind_values)
```

Comment: c.executemany works perfectly.  Thanks so much for showing me both methods.  I really appreciate your help.